# Wildfly logs streaming to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j, wildfly

I'm trying to configure Wildfly 18 to stream Log4j logs to Kafka topic. I did the following configuration:

**modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\kafka\clients**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module name="org.apache.kafka.clients" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.8">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="snappy-java-1.1.7.3.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="lz4-java-1.7.1.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="org.slf4j"/>
</dependencies>
```

**modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\kafka\log4jappender**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module name="org.apache.kafka.log4jappender" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.8">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="kafka-log4j-appender-2.6.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="org.slf4j"/>
    <module name="org.apache.kafka.clients" />
    <module name="org.jboss.log4j.logmanager" />
</dependencies>
```

**modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\log4j**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module name="org.apache.kafka.log4jappender" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.8">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="kafka-log4j-appender-2.6.0.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="org.slf4j"/>
    <module name="org.apache.kafka.clients" />
    <module name="org.jboss.log4j.logmanager" />
</dependencies>
```

and finally **modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\as\standalone**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module name="org.jboss.as.standalone" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.6">
 ...
<dependencies>
...
    <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" services="import"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.as.jmx" services="import"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.as.server" export="true"/>
    <module name="org.jboss.vfs" services="import"/>
    <module name="org.wildfly.security.elytron-private" services="import"/>
    <module name="org.apache.kafka.clients" />
</dependencies>
```

Then I have configured custom-handler and async-handler in logging subsystem. Unfortunately this works partially. Wildfly is trying to use the new logger, but Kafka libraries cannot find *org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer* class.

```
15:49:23,113 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-1) 
WFLYMSGAMQ0001: AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO.
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$6.applyPostCreate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:476)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$6.applyPostCreate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:460)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.doApplyPostCreate(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:313)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.doPrepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:345)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.prepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:291)
    at org.jboss.as.logging.logmanager.ConfigurationPersistence.prepare(ConfigurationPersistence.java:299)
    at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingOperations$CommitOperationStepHandler.execute(LoggingOperations.java:107)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:999)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:743)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:467)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1413)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:521)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:472)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:434)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:435)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:394)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:374)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer for configuration key.serializer: Class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer could not be found.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:727)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:473)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:466)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:129)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.java:396)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:326)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:298)
    at org.apache.kafka.log4jappender.KafkaLog4jAppender.getKafkaProducer(KafkaLog4jAppender.java:319)
    at org.apache.kafka.log4jappender.KafkaLog4jAppender.activateOptions(KafkaLog4jAppender.java:313)
    at org.jboss.as.logging.logmanager.Log4jAppenderHandler.activate(Log4jAppenderHandler.java:102)
    ... 22 more
```

If I'm not wrong setting *org.apache.kafka.clients* as a dependency in *org.jboss.as.standalone* should resolve this, but it is not working.

Comment: Personally, I would suggest logging to a rolling fileappender, then using some log-collection process on the host to collect that into Kafka. Otherwise, if Kafka becomes unavailable, and you get some error, then it'll be hard to get your logs

Comment: You shouldn't need to update the `org.jboss.as.standalone` module. What does your `custom-handler` configuration look like? Also you should be depending on `org.apache.log4j` and not the `org.jboss.logmanager.log4j` though that's not a huge deal.

Comment: you need add dependency to org.apache.kafka.clients in the module org.jboss.as.logging.logmanager